# Adjusting Gutter Width in Bootstrap 4

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, gutter

I'm trying to adjust the gutter via the variable "$grid-gutter-width-base", but it doesn't seem to be doing anything... Not sure if it's me or?

Comment: Please try and provide the full part of the code which is involved

Comment: `$grid-gutter-width-base:  70px;`

This would be the variable in question, it doesn't seem to affect bootstrap 4's grid at all